# Batch Script Saving to cd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

Basically I have everything in my script working and it saves the txt file to the c:/ drive with the line

" >> c:/information.txt "

But I would like it to save in the location of the batch file where it was opened.

Comment: The location of the batch file is %~dp0

Comment: So " %~dp0 >> text.txt " ? Doesn't work for me. Idk anything about this I need to be told exactly how to write it.

Comment: Everything to to the right of the redirection symbols is the path to where you want to write the file too.  Everything to the left is  what you want to redirect to your file.  I would think that is kind of obvious from your current working example.

Comment: Dude, I just started learning this stuff today none of this is obvious and I still don't have it working....

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Nothing I've tried works... %~dp0 ????? Text.txt.

Comment: `echo "%~dp0">> file.txt`-.bat location or `echo "%cd%">>file.txt`-current dir

Comment: @CizreK The directory separator on Windows is ``\`` (backslash) and not `/` (forwards slash). You can get help on available commands by opening a command prompt window and run `help`. Run a listed command with `/?` to get help on the command. Try it out with `call /?` which explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the executed batch file. See also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: @CizreK I recommend also to take a look on [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and even better [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/).

Comment: Just replace **`c:/`** with **`%~dp0`**!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a relative path [1] which is a path relative to the current location:

```
echo Hello World >>"information.txt"
```

You can do it with a absolute path, too. The path of the batch-file is stored in `%0` (=the first argument of each batch-file) [2] and can be modified to the drive `%~d0` and the path `%~p0` of the batch-file. You can easily combine both to get the path with the drive: `%~dp0`. [3]

```
echo Hello World >>"%~dp0information.txt"
```

In most cases both methods will act the same, but I recommend using the second method, because the current directory is not always the directory of the batch-file: If you execute the batch from an other directory (with another batch for example) you get this as directory for relative paths.

---

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths

[2] http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

[3] complete list of modifications contained in cmd help for the call and for command: `call/?`

Comment: I would recommend using one of either, `(Echo Hello World)>>"%~dp0information.txt"` or `>>"%~dp0information.txt" Echo Hello World` syntax. _Your posted method is `echo`ing unnecessary whitespace, removing that whitespace would be problematic should the string end with some integers, e.g. `2`_.

Comment: I preferred the simplest solution in this case, however I should have written the file name in quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately, now you've modified your answer to match my recommendation, it  is the same as @lit's answer, _posted between my comment and your modification_.

Comment: I don't really know how to do it then on this forum... should I let my answer as it is so notes and improvements are only in the comment-section or should I change my answer if someone has found an improvement/bug/etc?

Comment: @timlg07 it's the answer, that gets the votes, not the comments. So yes, edit your answer to be as good as possible (and notify the suggester (mentioning with `@name`), as I did, so they can remove their then obsolete comment)

Answer (score 0):

The `%~dp0` only works inside .bat file scripts. It will not work at the interactive command prompt.

```
@ECHO OFF
(ECHO Hello World)>>"%~dp0information.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my particular issue. 
Everything stayed the same except I removed "c:/"
I added "Pushd %~dp0" to the top of my script.